# Julia: Multiple dispatch for mutable struct items

Tags: julia

I am trying to split the function

```
function my_fun(A::MyStruct)
    if typeof(A.X) <: Nothing
        println("Case 1");
    else
        println("Case 2");
    end
end
```

into two methods on the basis of the type of `A.X`, where

```
mutable struct MyStruct
     t::Int64
     X::Union{Float64, Nothing}
end
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler only knows about types, not values, and therefore it cannot tell the difference between "Case 1" and "Case 2". You can either use dynamic dispatch, and use, for example a function barrier, or you can decide to *tell* the compiler the difference between the cases, by making your struct parametric.

I would suggest changing your code to this:

```
struct MyStruct{T}
     t::Int64
     X::T
end
```

(I changed the struct to be immutable, since you should almost always prefer immutables for simple structs like this).

Then,

```
my_fun(A::MyStruct{Nothing}) = println("Case 1")
my_fun(A::MyStruct{Float64}) = println("Case 2")
```

I you *cannot* do this, and absolutely *need* to have a type union, you can instead use a function barrier

```
_my_fun(::Type{Nothing}, A::MyStruct) = println("Case 1")
_my_fun(::Type{Float64}, A::MyStruct) = println("Case 2")
my_fun(A::MyStruct) = _my_fun(typeof(A.X), A)
```

Normally, I would prefer the first solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.